# How to return module assembly from base class using MEF?

Tags: c#, reflection, mef

I'm building a MEF module structure with a module interface and base class, including functionality for versioning and checking for updates. This is likely to be identical for most modules, so I'm planning to put method/property definitions into the base class.

Leaving aside whether the modules will check for updates automatically themselves (I don't expect them to necessarily), I would like to be able to retrieve, from the *module* assembly,

- Version info
- Update path (if built into the module)

What is the best (most MEF-way) of doing this? I'm more or less looking for the equivalent of `GetExecutingAssembly()` (which would return my host application - I think) or `GetAssembly()` (which would return my Interfaces assembly rather than the module one, given that it's in the base class) but to get my Module assembly rather than the application or base class one.